# How to interrupt SwingWorker by force?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, swingworker

If I call `SwingWorker.cancel(true)` it still continues execution, just setting `isCancelled()` to `true`. Is it possible to force interrupt?

Comment: @Leo `SwingWorker`, is at the end of the day, simply backed by a `Thread`.  The fact is, in Java, there is no way to stop a `Thread` unless the implementation supports monitoring the state of the `interrupted` flag and in some cases, blocking IO may not respond to the `interrupt` anyway.  The problem is not with the `SwingWorker`, the problem is with how `Thread` (and `Callable`) work...

Comment: @MadProgrammer good point, thx

Answer (score 2):

Just guessing, since you didn't post your code. You need to use the `isCancelled()` method inside your `doInBackground` method to specify when you want to stop. Post it (an example that reflects it) and I willl update my answer.

Since you said that you need a "brute" cancelation, you cannot do this with SwingWorker. Even if you work with Threads you should not do this. Take a look here: [Why are Thread.stop, Thread.suspend and Thread.resume deprecated?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html).

Comment: Yes, but this is a nice cancellation. But I need brute one.

Comment: So what does `boolean` parameter of `cancel()` method do? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#cancel(boolean)

Comment: @SuzanCioc `Thread`'s in Java can't be "brutally" stopped at all.  The implementation needs to provide support for been interruption in some manner

Comment: @SuzanCioc `cancel(boolean)` does exactly what it says, `Attempts to cancel execution of this task`, by calling `interrupt` on the underlying `Thread`.  Again, unless the implementation is checking the `interrupted` state of the `Thread`, it will do nothing

Comment: @MadProgrammer thread can be interrupted with `Thread#interrupt()`

Comment: @SuzanCioc BUT, as I said, unless the implementation (the code in the `run` method) is checking the state of [`isInterrupted`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isInterrupted()) and/or [`interrupted`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupted()) methods it will have no effect.  There simply is no way to force a thread to break/stop in Java WITHOUT the implementation first providing that support by checking the state of the `interrupted` flag...

Comment: @SuzanCioc Take a closer look at the [Interrupts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html) section of the [Concurrency trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html) for information...